# XSLT 1.0 (xsltproc) - How to use XSLT to parse XML values and add them into an already formed XML?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Output.xml is already formed.

I have to parse Input.xml to find Feature_ID for a Test_ID from the mapping in Input.xml and add it to Output.xml.

I was thinking this can be done with XSLT. How would the XSLT look like?

Input.xml

```
<Mapping>
  <Test>
    <Test_ID>123</Test_ID>
    <Feature_ID>111</Feature_ID>
  </Test>
   <Test>
    <Test_ID>456</Test_ID>
    <Feature_ID>222</Feature_ID>
  </Test>
</Mapping>
```

Current (already formed) Output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Test_ID>123</Test_ID>
    <Test_Name>Test_First</Test_Name>
  </Test>
   <Test>
    <Test_ID>456</Test_ID>
    <Test_Name>Test_Second</Test_Name>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Desired Output.xml

```
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Test_ID>123</Test_ID>
    <Test_Name>Test_First</Test_Name>
    <Feature_ID>111</Feature_ID>
  </Test>
   <Test>
    <Test_ID>456</Test_ID>
    <Test_Name>Test_Second</Test_Name>
    <Feature_ID>222</Feature_ID>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Also, how to pass Output.xml in the below command?

xsltproc XSLT.xsl Input.xml > Output_New.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy elements from one document to another, consider [`document()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#document) function in an XSLT script. Then call `xsltproc` on only run the main input document.

Actually, depending on your desired result, *Input* should be *Output* and vice versa since the root is *Suite*.

**XSLT** *(notice Input.xml referenced inside)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Suite">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Test"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Test">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:variable name="curr_id" select="Test_ID"/>
       <xsl:variable name="expr" select="document('FeatureID_Mapping.xml')/Mapping/Test[Test_ID = $curr_id]"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="Test_ID|Test_Name"/>
       <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$expr">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$expr/Feature_ID"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Feature_ID/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xsltproc**

```
xsltproc myScript.xsl Output.xml > myDesiredResult.xml
```

**Result**

```
<Suite>
  <Test>
    <Test_ID>123</Test_ID>
    <Test_Name>Test_First</Test_Name>
    <Feature_ID>111</Feature_ID>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <Test_ID>456</Test_ID>
    <Test_Name>Test_Second</Test_Name>
    <Feature_ID>222</Feature_ID>
  </Test>
</Suite>
```

Comment: Tried the above solution with the exact same code. But, myDesiredResult.xml is the same as Output.xml

Comment: Does this [Test_ID = $curr_id] try to get the index of the match?

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="document('Input.xml')/Mapping/Test[2]/Feature_ID"/>` .    If I hardcode the index like this, it works to print the second value for all output values. That means, in essence, the rest of this solution is working except that the index is not being calculated accurately with Test[Test_ID = $curr_id]

Comment: This has been tested with exact two inputs you posted. Possibly your actual XML differs in some way.

Comment: Is there a way to tweak your solution such that if there is no corresponding Feature ID found for a Test ID in the Mapping xml, it still prints an empty tag (<Feature_ID/>) in the output for the not found ones? Right now, it doesn't.